# Logging a cookie in CVS logs with JMeter

Tags: csv, testing, logging, jmeter

When logging in a CSV format in JMeter, is it possible to log a cookie value?

It seems to be possible log all cookie data when using XML logs (the option "Save Sampler Data (XML)"), but is there something like that, or better more specific (just a single specific cookie), for `.csv`?

We would like to use this to log a session ID cookie for all requests, so that it's possible to follow the requests in other application logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 JMeter Properties which can help you to get what you want:

1. `CookieManager.save.cookies` - CookieManager behaviour - should Cookies be stored as variables, can be "true" or "false". If it is set to "true" any cookie which is in scope will be accessible as a JMeter Variable in form of "COOKIE_cookieName". So if you have i.e. SESSIONID cookie it may be referred as "COOKIE_SESSIONID"
2. `sample_variables`- Optional list of JMeter variable names whose values are to be saved in the result data files.If you need more than 1 - the list should be comma-separated.

So if you set these 2 properties in i.e. *user.properties* file (in the /bin folder of your JMeter Installation) as

```
CookieManager.save.cookies=true
sample_variables=COOKIE_SESSIONID
```

your .jtl response will look something like:

> 1417446424571,459,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,10503,1,1,190,**your SESSIONID cookie value here**

NB

- JMEter restart is required to read properties from user.properties file
- You can override properties by passing them via -J command line argument as

> jmeter **-JCookieManager.save.cookies=true -Jsample_variables=COOKIE_SESSIONID** -n -t /path/to/your/test/plan -l /path/to/results/file.jtl

- See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on different JMeter properties and ways of setting and overriding them